# I'm trying to write a program for Palindromes but my output is not as expected

Tags: java, palindrome

this is my script

```
public class palindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rev = 0;

        Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("enter any value");

        int n = r.nextInt();

        while (n != 0) {
            rev = rev * 10 + n % 10;
            n = n / 10;
        }

        System.out.println(rev);

        if (n == rev) {
            System.out.println("number is palindrome");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not palindrome");    
    }
}
```

Comment: @NetVipeC for editing. Now it is understandable.

Comment: Insert this line after `n = n / 10;`: `System.out.println( "n = "+n+" rev = "+rev );` and voila, you'll be able to see what's going wrong.

Comment: BTW `01210` is a palindrome but `1210` is not. You are better off treating the input as a string.

Answer (score 0):

In your solution n is always 0.

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
    int palindrome = number; // copied number into variable
    int reverse = 0;

    while (palindrome != 0) {
        int remainder = palindrome % 10;
        reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
        palindrome = palindrome / 10;
    }

    // if original and reverse of number is equal means
    // number is palindrome in Java
    if (number == reverse) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

http://java67.blogspot.co.il/2012/09/palindrome-java-program-to-check-number.html

Comment: sorry to say,in my script While loop is perfect.But it's displaying the invalid output

Comment: What @Giovanni is exactly what I meant. At the end of the loop your n is always zero.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a copy of n into another variabile

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rev = 0;

    Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("enter any value");

    int n = r.nextInt();
    int original = n;

    while (n != 0) {
        rev = rev * 10 + n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
    }

    System.out.println(rev);

    if (original == rev) {
        System.out.println("number is palindrome");
    } else {
        System.out.println("not palindrome");    
}
```